# Creating customised records in each group of records in table using SQL. Scenario based

Tags: sql, plsql, scenarios

Tab_X

```
**Col_1 Col_2   Col_3**
A1      B1      10
A1      B2      7
A2      B1      15
A2      B2      6
```

OUTPUT

```
**Col_1 Col_2   Col_3** 
A1      B1      10  
A1      B2      7   
**A1        null            3    {10 - 7}**
A2      B1      15  
A2      B2      6   
**A2        Null            9   {15 - 6}**
```

All the groups of Col_1 should have a new record with col_3 value as below 
 = Col_3 {where col_2 = ‘B1’} - SUM(Col_3) {where col_2 <> ‘B1’}

Can someone please suggest SQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with Tab_X (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) as (
    select 'A1', 'B1', 10 from dual union all
    select 'A1', 'B2', 7  from dual union all
    select 'A2', 'B1', 15 from dual union all
    select 'A2', 'B2', 6  from dual
)
select *
from Tab_X
union all -- UPDATE, thanks @GordonLinoff
select Col_1
     , null
     , sum(Col_3 * case when Col_2 = 'B1' then 1 else -1 end)
from Tab_X
group by Col_1;
```

Comments:

- please use CTE (with clause) in your input specification to make answer more convenient
- please tag question of db vendor. From `plsql` tag I guess you have Oracle which unfortunately does not have `filter (where)` clause, hence the `sum (case when)` workaround
- might be solvable also using `group by rollup` but I couldn't think it up

**UPDATE: solution based on `group by rollup`**

```
with Tab_X (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) as (
    select 'A1', 'B1', 10 from dual union all
    select 'A1', 'B2', 7  from dual union all
    select 'A2', 'B1', 15 from dual union all
    select 'A2', 'B2', 6  from dual
)
select Col_1
     , null
     , case
         when grouping(Col_2) = 1 then sum(Col_3 * case when Col_2 = 'B1' then 1 else -1 end)
         else min(Col_3)
       end as Col_3
from Tab_X
group by Col_1, rollup (Col_2)
```

Comment: I further simplified query rewritimg `group by rollup` clause and avoiding `having` clause (overwriting answer, previous is available in version history).

Answer (score 0):

i used "lag" function for previous row's col_3 value.
And "Rank" column for catching to change col_1 column (A1 to A2).when it changes rank is increasing.

```html
with tab_x (col_1, col_2, col_3)
 as (select 'A1', 'B1', 10 from DUAL
     union
     select 'A1', 'B2', 7 from DUAL
     union
     select 'A2', 'B1', 15 from DUAL
     union
     select 'A2', 'B2', 6 from DUAL)  select x.col_1, x.col_2, x.col_3
from (select col_1,
             col_2,
             col_3,
             null RANK
        from (select col_1,
                     null col_2,
                     LAG (col_3, 1, 0) over (order by col_1) - col_3
                        as col_3,
                     null,
                     RANK ()
                        over (partition by col_1 order by col_1, col_2)
                        RANK
                from tab_x)
       where RANK = 2
      union all
      select col_1,
             col_2,
             col_3,               
             null RANK
        from tab_x
      order by col_1, col_2) x order by col_1, col_2
```

Comment: code only solutions are discouraged. adding some explanation can be helpful